# redirect 301 all categories links in wordpress + Redirection plugin

Tags: plugins, wordpress, redirect

how to redirect **all links**:

```
http://www.babynames.ir/esm/oldcat/page1/number/...
```

**to:**

```
http://www.babynames.ir/esm/newcat/page1/number/...
```

oldcat -> newcat

**im using:**
Permalink-Finder AND 404 redirect but mess all link.
using Redirection plugin but could not set the parameters...

Comment: Please perform some research into programming this and come back once you have done so and you were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

how about using htaccess like this
add to your .htaccess file after the `RewriteEngine On`

```
RedirectMatch 301 http://www.babynames.ir/esm/oldcat/(.*) http://www.babynames.ir/esm/newcat/$1
```

or may be like this

```
RewriteRule ^oldcat/?$ $1/newcat$2 [R=301,L]
```